# Audio Amp + battery = shutdown on high volume

Tags: audio, battery, reboot, phat-dac

I'm using the Raspberry Pi Zero W with a DAC, the [MiniAmp from HifiBerry](https://www.hifiberry.com/shop/boards/miniamp/) (2x3W) , and a pair of speaker 4Ohms 3W for making a connected speaker device.

Everything is working great until, in order to make the project "portable", I add a charger circuit ([Adafruit Powerboost 1000C](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2465)) and a 3.7V 3800mAh lithium battery (the one into [that package](https://www.amazon.fr/DollaTek-Batterie-Alimentation-Interrupteur-Framboise/dp/B07DJ47L7G/ref=pd_ybh_a_4?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=1SWJKGQNEBJWZR9MCFB5) but without the card).

Once powered through the battery (even if full charged or charging) the raspberry suddenly turns off when the audio volume exceeds a certain level…

I am noob into electricity rules, the battery and the charger circuit are supposed to be able to power a raspberry pi from what I read.
How can I achieve playing max volume sound (from the DAC) with a battery supply ?

Comment: `battery and the charger circuit are supposed to be able to power a raspberry pi` ... you have more than the RPi to power

Comment: yeah as I specified there is also an audio amp, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: provide enough power for the RPi and the audio amp

Comment: so useful answer..